# facebook comment box and facebook like bottton

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Do facebook like button and a facebook comment box on the same page require differnt app ids. I have a working comment box in my website. I like to add a "facebook like button". So do neeed to create a new app id for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need one app id per application.

Comment: How to create an app id for a like button. can you please point any tutorials available. I am completely new to Facebook apps

Comment: You should start by reading the Facebook pages on the subject, then open a new question to ask about any specific issues you encounter: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I have a working comment box in my website. I like to add a "facebook like button". So do I need to create a new app id for that ?

Comment: No. follow the instructions on the link I posted, it'll generate the code for you

Comment: Moreover, don't include the `<script...` part but once. Don't just copy and paste on your page